# Nixie Clock with Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: high-voltage, overheat, nixie, raspberry-pi-pico

[image: circuit and picture]

I am trying to make a multifunctional nixie clock controlled with 2 **Raspberry Pi Pico**s. Because of my mistake I can't plug every **IN-12B**s into sockets. So I can only test a maximum of 4 at a time. After several tests, it was confirmed that all numbers were displayed in all digits.

Instead, I found two problems:

First, when testing 4 sockets, the edges of 7 or 5 did not light up properly (blue circle in picture ). There was no problem when testing 3 sockets. I am using **NCH6100HV** to apply 170 voltage. This module can control voltage from 85 to 235 by turning variable resistance.

Second, **K155ID1**s (white circles in picture) are getting hotter and hotter when I apply voltages. I am using **XL4015 Adjustable Voltage Stepper** to apply 5 V.

Could you help me to solve both problems? Also any advice to improve this thing is very much appreciated.

Comment: As the K155ID1s are getting hotter, I recommend performing a short-circuit test. Take your multimeter and test the PCB to find out if there is an accidental short circuit somewhere.

Comment: @liaifat85 thank you for your advice! Should I remove K155ID1,RASPBERRYPI,nixie tubes from sockets before testing PCB??

Comment: I think it's better to do so. Only the bare PCB should be tested first if possible. If no problem is found, then the test should be done with components. Also check for broken traces.